# Как реализовать повторение строки в kotlin?

Tags: python, строки, kotlin

У меня есть строка и я хочу, чтоб строка повторилась n раз. Как это реализовать в kotlin?

В питоне можно умножить строку на число. Какие аналоги есть в котлине?

Comment: Либо вы неправильно выразились либо не поняли что спросили

Comment: У меня есть строка и я хочу, чтоб строка повторилась n раз. То есть было "abc", стало "abcabcabc". В питоне можно писать string * n и это выполняется, а как это делать в kotlin? Возможно я что-то не правильно написал, но буду благодарен, если вы поправите меня и укажите на ошибку в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [repeat](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html):

```kotlin
println("abc".repeat(3))
```

Результат:

```
abcabcabc
```